# Plain and empty Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, empty

We want to have a plain empty sandbox - one without any configuration metadata or data from Production.

Is it possible to have such a sandbox?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Not easily, no. You would have to create a sandbox and then delete everything. To do this, I would recommend creating a destructive changes ANT script, but be advised not everything can be removed that way.

For more information on the Migration Tool, see the [guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sandbox but without the data, objects, classes, workflow etc. from Production then perhaps get a new Developer org. It's not a sandbox, but it won't have anything from Production in it. What is the reason you need this though?

Comment: Dev orgs still come pre-populated with data and some configuration so even they aren't clean slates.

Comment: A developer org (not a developer sandbox) will be as clean a slate as you can get, won't it?

Comment: I still want the sandbox from Production because we want to test Disaster Recovery module if at all the Salesforce org is corrupted (Production) and we have a sandbox org in which we can start from scratch using PVCS and Eclipse components (to deploy).

Comment: If you're trying to test the scenario when your production org is totally corrupted and you want to know if you can restore it from your version control repository, then you could try deploying from your local filesystem (version control) to a brand new developer org (representing your production system completely wiped)

Comment: If you want to start from ground zero, a Developer Edition is definitely the way to go. Otherwise, you're going to have to create the sandbox, wipe out all of metadata configuration, and then test. Wiping out a Developer Edition takes just a minute compared to wiping a sandbox clean.