# How to create an empty Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, metadata, ant

I would like to create an empty (objects and data) sandbox with the same license and features than my prod org to test new implementations.

I know that we can use and new dev org. However, this will have more features than our prod org (like connect, service cloud, etc.). We don't want to use a feature that then, is not available in our prod org.

Is there any way to achieve this? Someone already ask this on 2013 ([Plain and empty Sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/plain-and-empty-sandbox)). But three years later something must have changed

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing's changed, but you can [vote on this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PTxkQAG).

Comment: I can't believe that this is not possible, how can I approach this? Any recommendation?

Comment: I'm trying to ask for an update on this, that's why put the link to the previous question, avoiding duplicates.